# Automatically detect center of collection view cell selected on rotation

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have the following code in `didSelectItemAt indexPath` of `collectionview`

```
//To find center of collectionview cell
let attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
print("center: \((attributes?.center)!)")
```

I get the following output when I select a cell in `portrait` mode

```
center: (659.5, 200.0)
```

I like to get the following as soon as I rotate it to `landscape` mode `automatically`, which is the center of cell in the `landscape` mode, without me selecting it manually.

```
center: (206.0, 200.0)
```

Is there a way to achieve this, so that I can pass it as `transition.start = center` in `didSelectItemAt IndexPath` for the transition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implement `func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval)` method of `UIViewController` to get a callback whenever the device's orientation is changed and get the `center` of selected `UICollectionViewCell` in it.

You can use `indexPathsForSelectedItems` on `UICollectionView` to get the `indexPath` of the selected `UICollectionViewCell`.

```
override func willRotate(to toInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation, duration: TimeInterval)
{
    if let indexPath = self.collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first
    {
        let attributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes? = collectionView.layoutAttributesForItem(at: indexPath)
        print("center: \((attributes?.center)!)")
    }
}
```

Comment: This works, but I want to pass the center variable in didSelectItem at function.

Comment: I don’t understand why you want to pass it in didSelectItem if you are getting it using the attributes. Please specify your requirements more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for your response, because I want to make it as a start for my transition, I edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can override `viewWillTransitionToSize()` in your view controller to detect rotational changes.

```
 override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    if UIDevice.currentDevice().orientation.isLandscape.boolValue {
        print("Landscape")
        // Get collection view center here
    } else {
        print("Portrait")
        // Get collection view center here
    }
}
```